# Rename files in Lightroom during export

Tags: lightroom, filenames

When exporting my images from Lightroom, I want to rename them, based upon the image name and its mapping in a CSV file. Ideally, I would want something like this:

[image: Snapshot of the Export panel]

When the user after editing goes to `Export` under `File` menu. Inside the `File Naming` panel above, one should be able to input the CSV file containing the mapping. Hence once exported, the new Images will be named consistently with what I need rather than the default ones provided by LightRoom.

Using the plugin [LRTransporter](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrtransporter.php?sec=main) one can do it while Importing images (storing the new name under Caption and then renaming all using Batch Rename). But it is tedious.

What I need to know is that, can we build such plugin which can do it? If yes I would move ahead with constructing it.

Comment: Me (as a c# developer) would rather write a little tool for that than a plugin.

Comment: First: you want to *export* images with a different name? Or you simply want to rename the master files Lightroom uses? From the question I'd think the latter but you're showing the Export dialog so I'm not sure.

Comment: @DanWolfgang I want to export Images with a different name.

Comment: Well then, I'm going to agree with @gsharp: given that LR/Transporter is already doing so much of the work for you, I'd just write a little Perl script to automate the renaming.

Comment: @DanWolfgang Yes! true, but that will be one more step after the export. The aim is to reduce that.

Comment: You can't put this mapping in the EXIF somewhere instead? If you could, then the exporter could use that as part of a custom name.

Comment: There are several ways that may work, but it would be easier for us to recommend a way if we knew exactly what the mapping involves. Is it just mapping the original name to a new name, and if so, what is the new name/format? The File Naming custom settings are quite flexible.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to know is that, can we build such plugin which can do it?

Yes, we can. But it would be much easier to write an external script to do it after Lightroom has finished processing. Give it a try.